# uWSGI and Python on Arch Linux, encoding failure

Tags: python, uwsgi, arch-linux

I am running an Arch Linux box and have setup a Python 3.4 virtualenv.

I have a uwsgi vassal being run by the emperor, which specifies the following ini: (some snipped for brevity)

```
[uwsgi]
virtualenv = /opt/lib/virtualenvs/bartek
socket = /tmp/bartek.sock
module = app
callable = app
plugins = python
```

When I run this and view the uwsgi log file, I consistently get this:

```
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/bartek.sock fd 3
Python version: 3.4.1 (default, May 19 2014, 17:23:49)  [GCC 4.9.0 20140507 (prerelease)]
Set PythonHome to /opt/lib/virtualenvs/bartek
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

This seems to be potentially related to the virtualenv? When I remove `virtualenv` from uwsgi config, it fails on missing packages instead of complaining about this encoding. I'd prefer to keep using  a virtualenv, though!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I guess this is caused by the virtualenv parameter, when I changed the virtualenv to /, everything is OK.

Comment: But what if a virtualenv is required to run the app?